# How to get paragraph result from solr keyword search after using tika to index some documents?

Tags: solr, solrj, apache-tika

I use TIKA to index documents. then I want to get the whole paragraph from paragraph start to the paragraph end which contains the key words. I tried to use HighlightFragsize but it does not work. For example: there is a document like below:

- When I was very small, my parents took me to many places, because they wanted me to learn more about the world. Thanks to them, I
  witnessed the variety of the world and a lot of beautiful scenery.
- But no matter where I go, in my heart, the place with the most
  beautiful scenery is my hometown.

there are two paragraphs above. If I search 'my parents', I hope I can get the whole paragraph "When I was very small, my parents....... a lot of beautiful scenery". not only part of this paragraph. I used HighlightFragsize to limit the sentence, but the result is not what I want. Please help. thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided a lot of information to go off of but I'm assuming that you're using a highlighter so here are a couple of things you should check for:

1. The field that holds your parsed data - is it stored? Can you see the entire contents?
2. If (1), is the text longer than 51200 chars? The default highlighter configuration has a setting `maxAnalyzedChars` that is set to `51200`. This means that the highlighter will not process more than 51200 characters from a highlighted field in a matched document to look for highlights. If this is the case, increase this value until you get the desired results.

Highlighting on extremely large fields may incur a significant performance penalty which you should be mindful of before choosing a configuration.
See [this](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_4/highlighting.html) for more details.

### UPDATE

I don't think there's any parameter called HighlightFragsize but there's one called `hl.fragsize` which can do what you want when set to zero.

Try the following query and see if it works for you:
`q=my+parents&hl=true&hl.fl=my_field&hl.fragsize=0`

Additionally, you should, in any case, be mindful of the first 2 points I posted above.

**UPDATE 2**
I don’t think there’s a direct way to do what you’re looking for. You could possibly split up your field into a multi valued field with each paragraph being stored as a separate value.

You can then possibly use `hl.preserveMulti`, `hl.maxMultiValuedToExamine` and `hl.maxMultiValuedToMatch` to achieve what you need.

Comment: thanks for replying. Please see my question again. I have updated it. thanks

Comment: If I use hl.fragsize=0, which means I will get all the contents of the document, but I just want to get one of these two paragraphs.